# React Testing Library testing for the saving state of a button

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a button that briefly changes text to the text `Saving` when clicked. How can I test for this state? I suspect the name change happens so quickly it is not being picked up rather than it being broken.

```js
await act(() => {
  const saveButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Save" });
  fireEvent.click(saveButton);
  expect(saveButton).toHaveAttribute("name", "Saving");
});
```

Can this be done without simulating a slow down in the API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the `expect()` and `saveButton` out from `act()`.

```js
const saveButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Save" });

await act(() => {
  fireEvent.click(saveButton);
});

expect(saveButton).toHaveAttribute("name", "Saving");
```

When the `expect()` is in the `act()` it does not wait for the `fireEvent.click(saveButton)`.

**Note**:

On the [intro example](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro), it does not use the `act()` for user event, just transforms the `test()` to an `async` function and uses `await` for user events before the assertions.